# Angular Routes or Sub components

Tags: angular, routes, subcomponent

I Am creating CRUD for a Journey Entity and have created two components in Angular.

- List
- edit

The list gets all the journeys from a service and displays them.
The edit has a form which will add anew journey or edit a journey if it's passed a journey id.

I have a lot of entities and am using routing with url parameters to achieve this:

```
     <a mat-button [routerLink]="['/journey-edit', journey.id]">{{journey.name}}</a>
```

I have now discovered Sub components where i can pass a journey from the list to the edit and then just hide the list:

```
    <app-journey-view *ngIf="currentJourney" [journey]="currentJourney"></app-journey-view>
```

Now I am stuck. Which way do I proceed?

- Do I need routing at all
- can I mix routing with subcomponents
- Authentication is on my route. Will that work with subcomponents:

  ```
   {
   path: 'journey-list',
   component: JourneyListComponent,
   canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
   },
  ```

This app will have many entities and most entities will be linked through a relational database.

Answer (score 1):

Just use routing. If you hide the list you cannot get to the specific item from url.

```js
{ 
  path: 'journey',
  children:[
    { path: 'journey-list', component: JourneyListComponent},
    { path: ':id', component: JourneyDetailComponent},
    { path: 'edit/:id', component: JourneyEditComponent}
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have been passing the specific item to the subcomponent when you click on one item in the list (parent)